# How to set HTML5 video subtitle directly by text?

Tags: html, html5-video, subtitle

For example, this is a `video` tag with a `track` inside it.

```
<video src='some_video.mp4'>
    <track id='some_subtitle' kind='subtitles'>
</video>
```

I don't want to set the `src` attribute of the `track` tag, because I'm editing the subtitle just on the page. I've tried something like

```
document.getElementById('some_subtitle').value = '1\n0.00 --> 5.00\nSubtitle';
```

But doesn't work. Could anyone tell me What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
video = document.getElementById('vid');
track = video.addTextTrack('captions');
track.mode = "showing";
track.addCue(new VTTCue(0, 5, 'Subtitle'));
track.addCue(new VTTCue(10, 15, 'Hi, cue!'));
```

and so on. There's also a removeCue method.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/#toc-cues-js
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#text-track